# resource identified by request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

My Controller method is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/instances",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Set<ArchivalInstance> findAllInstances() {
    System.out.println("finding all instances");
    Set<ArchivalInstance> set=archivalInstanceService.getAllArchivalInstance();
    return set;
}
```

and ajax call in my jsp

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
                function() {
                    $.getJSON('instances.html', {
                        ajax : 'true'
                    }, function(data) {
                        alert("data ="+data.instanceName);
                    });
                });
    </script>
```

And I'm getting following error when i see Network tab in developer tools(in chrome browser)

```
<Response>
    The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers


<header>
    Request URL:http://localhost:8082/ArchivalSearchTool/instances.html?ajax=true
    Request Method:GET
    Status Code:406 Not Acceptable
    Request Headersview source
    Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

I tried to return boolean instead of set but not able to get response. Please tell me where i need to change or any jar needs to be added?

Comment: You should make sure that your project includes the necessary Jackson libraries.

Comment: @willOEM Thank you. I added Jackson libraries. It's working now